# DX79SI Boot Issues

Tags: boot, motherboard

I'm building a new computer with these specs:

Intel® Core™ i7-3970X

The Intel® Desktop Board DX79SI

Intel® SSD 520 Series 240 GB SSD

Gigabyte AMD Radeon HD 7970 (WindForce)

Corsair Hydro Series Extreme Performance Liquid CPU Cooler H80i

Corsair Dominator 16GB (4x4GB) DDR3 2133 MHz

Corsair Professional Series  AX 850 Watt ATX/EPS Modular 80 PLUS Gold (AX850)

Asus 24xDVD-RW Serial ATA Internal OEM Drive DRW-24B1ST (Black)

WD Green Desktop 1TB SATA 6.0 GB/s

Cooler Master HAF X - Full Tower Computer Case with USB 3.0 Ports and Windowed Side Panel (RC-942-KKN1)

Windows 8 (USB)

Windows 7 SP1 (DVD)

I'm running into some issues booting up Windows 8/7 OS installation for a clean install. I have updated the BIOS to the latest update and the BIOS boots up just fine and I can go into the setup and change things around.

Whenever I let the BIOS continue past the splash screen I get a '0_' code in the bottom right hand corner of my screen and the LED display on the motherboard says '00'.

When I go into the boot menu by pressing F10 during the splash screen and try to boot from my usb device, I get a '0' in the bottom right corner of my screen then '00' on the motherboard. The screen also keeps displaying the boot menu with all of my options, but I cannot interact with it. The same thing happens when I try to boot from my DVD drive, except I get a repeated beeping noise.

Also I can only enter BIOS setup when a usb device in connected to the front panel of the case.

Comment: If you disconnect all peripherals (including your KB and mouse) does it boot?

Comment: Yes, it still boots.

Comment: Ok, but does it boot as expected, like into Windows?  BTW: POST code [00 means "Ready to boot"](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-025434.htm#sequence), so it displays 00, and control is then passed to the OS to complete the boot.  Also, have you tried detaching ALL things but CPU, RAM, Video and your boot drive, and then attempting a boot?  The fact that you can't get into the BIOS without something in the USB port is weird, and makes me wonder if you've wired something wrong during assembly.

Comment: Does that mainboard allow you to revert to the previous BIOS version?

Comment: @techie007 Well, I do not have an OS installed on any of my drives. All of my parts are new, so it really doesn't have anything to boot to. I'll try disconnecting everything but the cpu, ram, and videocard and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the bios update, if it`s goes wrong - it can stack the system, in that case , i would try a new bios update or roll back to the previous bios version .